# How can I get a forward iterator to the last element?

Tags: c++, iterator, traversal

I'm looking for a convenient option to get the last element from a container/range which only supports forward traversal, which essentially means I cannot do stuff like `std::prev(std::end())`. For now the only idea I have is this one:

```
const std::forward_list<int> list{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto it = list.cbegin();
std::advance(it, std::distance(it, list.cend()) - 1);
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

Is there a more convenient way to get to the last element of a forward traversal range? Boost is welcome.

Comment: `auto it = list.end() ; ` `--it` ?

Comment: @Irelia Forward iterators cannot move backwards, your code won't compile.

Comment: so `auto it = list.end() -1 ` won't work either?

Comment: Walk the list with a forward sniffing iterator, return the previous successful iterator.

Comment: @Irelia Nope, UB

Comment: @Irelia you literally cannot move a forward iterator backwards, whatever you try. Nodes of `forward_list`, for example, do not have pointers to previous nodes, which makes moving backwards impossible.

Comment: I see, well then I have no idea

Comment: I'd say you have XY problem. Why did you choose a container with forward iterator only if you need to access last element? It is possible, as Eljay said, but it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: Such are the wages of a monodirectional data structure. What you save in space overhead and lower complexity in the data structure you'll burn up in the users of the data structure as soon as you have to step off of its very narrow rails.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen because I work in a team and have to use someone else's containers

Comment: @Kaiyakha well, _teamwork_ means to discuss such design decision amongst the whole team with equal rights to address concerns, no?

Comment: Might be worth working up a business case demonstrating that use of algorithm X allows delivery of that module in Time t, but increases the delivery time of the four modules that use it to tn, ultimately delaying the project more than tn for module X and only t for the other four.

Comment: Mind you, have a non-argumentative chat with the other developer. They may have already considered your usecase and have a better solution.

Comment: @Kaiyakha well, the answer is right there for your service. There's no better way to solve that staying within the realm of defined behavior. That's ammunition to discuss in the team, no? I often did this, when I had doubts about design desicions of the _"team gurus"_. Asked a question at SO, to get backing up my doubts.

Comment: @Kaiyakha -- The comment section is for comments, not answers.

Comment: Anyway, there is no easy-and-quick way to find the last item of `std::forward_list`. If you have to do it regularly, you're using the wrong data structure OR you're using the wrong algorithm. See if the algorithm can be adapted to run backward so you only need rapid access to the first item.

Answer (score 4):

make a helper function that iterates until the next one would the end

```
template<class iterator>
iterator find_next_to_last(iterator first, iterator last) {
    assert(first != last);
    iterator next = first;
    while(++next != last)
        first = next;
    return first;
}
```

Comment: Should also check `if (first == last)` for an empty list, unless empty list is disallowed by contract (in which case `assert(first != last);`).

Comment: @Eljay good catch! After some thought, I decided to disallow by contract.

Answer (score 1):

I like Mooing Duck's answer, but I thought a tiny tweak to handle an empty list would be nice.  Although nothing wrong with disallowing that situation by contract, plenty of functions in the standard library impose constraints by contract.

But to answer your question...

> Is there a more convenient way to get to the last element of a forward traversal range?

...**no**, there is not a more convenient way in general.  You need to walk the forward list to get to the back most element.  (Assuming you can't cache an iterator to the back most element.)

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include<cassert>

template <typename I>
auto back(I it, I last) {
    using std::next;
    auto n = it;

    while (n != last) {
        it = std::exchange(n, next(n));
    }

    return it;
}

// Container-to-iterator-pair convenience function.
template <typename C>
auto back(C const& c) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return back(begin(c), end(c));
}

static
auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::forward_list<int> const& l) -> std::ostream& {
    auto sep = "";

    for (auto&& x : l) {
        out << std::exchange(sep, " ") << x;
    }

    return out;
}

template <typename C, typename I>
struct print {
    C const& container;
    I const& it;
    print(C const& c, I const& i) : container{c}, it{i} {}
    bool valid() const {
        using std::begin;
        using std::end;
        using std::next;
        auto b = begin(container);
        auto e = end(container);
        while(b != e) {
            if (it == b) return true;
            b = next(b);
        }
        return it == e;
    }

    template <typename CC, typename II>
    friend auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, print<CC, II> const& p) -> std::ostream& {
        using std::end;
        assert(p.valid());

        if (end(p.container) == p.it) {
            return out << "(end)";
        }

        return out << *p.it;
    }
};
print(struct allow_ctad_t, struct allow2_ctad_t)->print<void, void>;

int main() {
    std::forward_list<int> const list{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << list << "\n";
    auto it = back(list);
    std::cout << print(list, it) << "\n";
    std::cout << print(list, list.end()) << "\n";
}
```